# How to invoke a URL from a WCF REST service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF REST service which needs to invoke a URL (could be a webpage, REST service, etc.) and pass some values to it (something like http://xyz.com/callback?a=1&b=2). It does not need to worry about the response (just invoke and forget). What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As Matthew stated, the HttpWebRequest is the ideal way for making web requests via code.  You should use a tool like Fiddler to capture the traffic to the website, then work on rebuilding the same type of request in your code.  I have a helper class that I use to to this, but here is a piece of it that I use when I'm sending data along with a request.

```
    public static string HttpRequest(string requestType, string contentType, string parameters, string URI, CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        string results = string.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);

        req.CookieContainer = cookies;
        req.Method = requestType;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ContentLength = 0;
        req.ContentType = contentType;
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters))
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);
            req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
        }

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            if (HttpStatusCode.OK == response.StatusCode)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                // Content-Length header is not trustable, but makes a good hint.        
                // Responses longer than int size will throw an exception here!        
                int length = (int)response.ContentLength;
                const int bufSizeMax = 65536;

                // max read buffer size conserves memory        
                const int bufSizeMin = 8192;

                // min size prevents numerous small reads        
                // Use Content-Length if between bufSizeMax and bufSizeMin        
                int bufSize = bufSizeMin;
                if (length > bufSize) bufSize = length > bufSizeMax ? bufSizeMax : length;

                // Allocate buffer and StringBuilder for reading response        
                byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bufSize);

                // Read response stream until end        
                while ((length = responseStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) != 0)
                    sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, length));

                results = sb.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                results = "Failed Response : " + response.StatusCode;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error("WebHelper.HttpRequest", exception);
        }

        return results;
    }
```

NOTE: Might be some calls to other helpers, but the basic flow show give you an idea of what you need to do.